# Create SweepGradient in onDraw of custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw

**Background**

For my app, I'm creating a custom view that shows a percentage, between 0% and 300%, which shows how good the user is doing compared to the average, a lower percentage being a better score. The custom view is a simple circle, with a `SweepGradient`, coloring from green to yellow (for the first 100%), from yellow to orange (for the second 100%) or from orange to red (for the third 100%).

**Problem**

The center of the gradient should be located in the center of the custom view, thus the `x` would be at `canvas.getWidth/2`. However, I'm only able to reach the canvas in the `onDraw` method of the view. Since `SweepGradient` is immutable, I have to create it with its location (and colors) in the `onDraw` method. Creating a new Gradient on every `onDraw` is not efficient or recommended, since one should not construct new objects in `onDraw`.

**Question**

How can I efficiently setup such a gradient at the center of a view, while not creating it on onDraw?

*Extra question: 
Why is SweepRelease immutable?*

Comment: see `onSizeChanged`

Comment: @pskink: thank you, but is `onSizeChanged` always called before the first onDraw? I should be able to rely on this so that the gradient always exists when performing the `onDraw` method.

Comment: yes, first is "measure / layout phase", then "draw phase" when the size is already known

Comment: How do you solve it?

Comment: It seems every body just put "new SweepGradient" in onDraw()